# Why swagger adds extra field to documentation?

Tags: symfony, swagger

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=SellerSalesChannel::class)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Groups("sellerAddressWithChannel")
 */ // todo why does this appear in response?
private $sellerChannel;
```

So there is this field which I do not want to see in documentation. The group sellerAddressWithChannel is not used anywhere. So why this field can be added to swagger documentation? What should I check?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found:

In SellersSalesChannel needed to set groups

```
/**
 *
 * @JMS\Groups({"test"})
 * @SWG\Property(type="array", @SWG\Items(
 *     ref=@Model(type=SellerAddress::class, groups={"full"})
 * ))
 */
private $sellerAddresses;
```

in line ref=@Model. Otherwise it was just showing all fields from SellerAddress